# Необходимо по нажатию кнопки перейти на другую вкладку

Tags: android, bottom-navigation-view

я использую bottom navigation activity и на одной из вкладок есть кнопка, по нажатию на которую необходимо перейти на другую вкладку, как правильно написать код в классе активити ?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener. В теле свитча определите ид элемента, на котором выполнено нажатие и выполните навигацию удобным вам способом (открывайте фрагмент или активити).

```kotlin
bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
            when(item.itemId) {
                R.id.scanner -> {

                  
                    true
                }
                R.id.results -> {
          
                    true
                }
                R.id.help -> {
                    val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    startActivity(i)
                    false
                }
                else -> false
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас в разметке есть `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView`, к которому прикручено с помощью `app:menu` какое-то меню с элементами.
Каждый из этих элементов имеет какое-то уникальное `id`.
Когда вам надо перейти на другую вкладку, просто меняете id выбранного элемента.

```
bottomNavigationView.selectedItemId = R.id.tab_2
```

Соответственно обработчик `bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { ... }` должен быть определен.